# postgres password error : Please enter the password for the user 'postgres' to connect the server - "PostgreSQL 13"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I having issue connection to postgres, I am installing at windows 10 via the EDB installer (version 13.2) . I follow all the steps it install fine however when I try to enter the default database using pgadmin   it I always get stuck at this error :

> `Please enter the password for the user 'postgres' to connect the server - "PostgreSQL 13"`

during instalation postgres ask me to specify my master Password. then when instalation finish and I open my pgadmin it again ask me to enter the master password so I did and I was able to successfully login but when I try to open the default database that when it ask me to enter password for posgres  user , I try to use the my master password but it did not work

I installed and uninstall it many time with no success. I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64290055/8857703) so I did change the Method in `pg_hba.config` from  `scram-sha-256` to `trust` however when I executed this command `psql -U postgres` it again asked me for the password

any help please

Comment: Your description is very vague. That makes it very hard to determine what you did wrong. You should try harder: What operation system? How exactly did you install PostgreSQL? What choices did you make during the installation process? What are the exact steps you did when you messed with `pg_hba.conf`? etc, etc.

Comment: When you installed Postgres using the EDB installer(I presume) it asked you to create an admin password. That is the password you need to use for the `postgres` user.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  during instalation yes exacttly it ask me to specify my master Password. then when instalation finish and I open my pgadmin it again ask me to enter the master password so I did and I was able to successfully login but when I try to open the default database that when it ask me to enter password for `posgres ` user , I try to use the my master password but it did not work

Comment: Are you confusing the password that was requested here [EDB Installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/supported-open-source/postgresql/installer/02_installing_postgresql_with_the_graphical_installation_wizard/01_invoking_the_graphical_installer/) with the one for opening `pgAdmin`?

Comment: no I am not confusing them.  the password in EDB installer is master password I already used it and I was alble to enter `pgadmin` , the password requested is the password for 'postgres' user

Comment: Per the link I posted the password you created via the installer is for the `postgres` user. So either you are not remembering the password correctly or you are connecting to a Postgres instance that was not set up by the installer and uses a different password.

Comment: @Youssef, I'm in the same boat: I've installed PostGreSQL and PGAdmin4 every which way I can think of, and nothing is working, and I'm getting the exact same issue: during installation, you are prompted to set a Master password. When you first open PGA4, you have to put in your master password. Having successfully remembered it from 22 seconds earlier, I can get into PGA4, but then get prompted for the password for user 'postgres' as soon as I touch the default instance, and no, the master password does NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

You made the same mistake I did: you installed pgAdmin4 without installing [postGreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) server itself. The server installation does indeed set the Master password **and** the postgres user password at the same time, as the commenters were trying to point out. JUST installing pgAdmin sets a master password for the Admin environment. I don't really understand how there's not a more useful error for trying to connect to a server instance that doesn't actually exist, but here we are.

Answer (score 0):

try it. it resolves for me
step 1
[image: step1]

step2
[image]