# cannot connect to Postgres - password unknown

Tags: postgresql, connection

I can't connect on postgresql.

when i go on pgadmin>server>postgresql, it asked me "please enter the password for the user 'postgres' to connect the server?

I have windows 10 and postgresql 14.

But I don't have this password.
What can I do?

[image]

Comment: You specified that password when you created the database user. Or if you trying to connect as the superuser, then you specified the password when you installed Postgres.

Comment: That's the point. I don't specify any password when i installed postgre.

Comment: You can visit this link for solution
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198359/pg-admin-4-password-for-postgres-user-when-trying-to-connect-to-postgresql-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198359/pg-admin-4-password-for-postgres-user-when-trying-to-connect-to-postgresql-1)

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me.
Change METHOD of all rows in your `pg_hba.conf` file from `scram-sha-256` to `trust` (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data\pg_hba.conf). This will disable password for your DB.
Click on any database in postgresql to use Query Tool.

In Query Tool type `ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'User_password';`
`postgres` is default username, execute it.
This way you can set up a password for your DB, after that go back to the first step and change it back from `trust` to `scram-sha-256`.